# How to add a rule for loggin packets in ufw

Tags: connection, firewall, ufw

I'm seeing a lot of connections with source 0.0.0.0 and destination 0.0.0.0 in conntrack. I want to log these packets which have source 0.0.0.0 and destination 0.0.0.0 so that I can digg this issue further.

Can you tell me how can I add a rule which logs a packet in ufw?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sudo ufw logging on

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW for the full Ubuntu Community documentation.

Comment: UFW loging is enabled, but I need but I need to log these specific packets (with source 0.0.0.0 and destination 0.0.0.0).

Comment: In Linux the IP typically 0.0.0.0 means to listen on all eth cards.